# Notes format from Mountain Lion (V1) to Mavericks (V2): how to migrate?

Tags: macos, migration, notes.app

My previous Mac's hard drive died, but I had backups, so I am migrating all its data to a new Mac. The only problem: my previous computer had Mountain Lion and the new one has Mavericks, so the data in the Notes app seems to be stored in a different format. In my backup, I see the notes in:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes
```

And I see these files:

```
NotesV1.storedata
NotesV1.storedata-shm
NotesV1.storedata-wal
```

In my new computer, in Mavericks, I see the notes in the same path, but the files are:

```
NotesV2.storedata
NotesV2.storedata-shm
NotesV2.storedata-wal
```

So, is there any difference between V1 notes files and V2? Can I just overwrite them with my old note files?

Comment: If you're actually migrating, presumably it will figure it out. If you're just copying, I wouldn't be so sure. It might offer to update on first launch...

Comment: Well, I am using the word "migrate", but in truth I'm not using Migration Assistant or anything like that; as I said, my previous Mac died, so I'm copying everything from backups by hand.